# how to merge "flow-through" edges in spark graphframes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, graph-algorithm, spark-graphx, graphframes

Would the following graph algorithm be possible to implement with Spark GraphFrames?

Given a graph, I'd like to remove nodes that have exactly one incoming edge and one outgoing edge, and merge the two edges into one edge. For instance, assume the we have:

[image: pre-merging]

then the graph simplification algorithm would remove the two nodes in the middle (and merge the edges and add up the weights of 1, 8, 3 into 12). And similarly for top-right portion merge the two edges into one (and add up edge weights 2 and 1 into 3)

[image: post-merging]

I found a similar solution using networkx here:
[Remove all nodes in a networkx DiGraph with in-degree and out-degree equal to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735252/remove-all-nodes-in-a-networkx-digraph-with-in-degree-and-out-degree-equal-to-1)

But I can't use networkx as my graph is very large, so I'd like to see if it is possible to implement this with Spark GraphFrames